# JAvaFX modular from ID(intellij) worksnonmodular: Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, modular

**Can anyone explain to me where the mistake is?**

For several days I have been trying to clarify this issue:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

1. **Non-modular from IDE**

- create a JavaFX project
- Attach the Library
- in the VM Option field :
  **--module-path "C:\opt\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.fxml, javafx.controls**

= result: Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this applicatio

2)**modular from IDE **

- create a file: module-info.java

```
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    
    opens sample;
```

Result: run